# How to used the mousescroll to as a modal function to, for example, move the object?

Tags: python, scripting

For example, in the template in the text editor has an example script that utilizes a modal function with mousemove to change the location of the object along and axis, how can I use the same function, but instead it's the scroller that controls the function ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`event.type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Event.html#bpy.types.Event.type) that you get within `modal()` will be `WHEELUPMOUSE` or `WHEELDOWNMOUSE` when the scrollwheel is used.

```
def modal(self, context, event):
    if event.type == 'WHEELUPMOUSE':
        context.object.location.x += 0.5
    elif event.type == 'WHEELDOWNMOUSE':
        context.object.location.x -= 0.5
    elif event.type == 'ESC':
        return {'CANCELLED'}

    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```